# Can I run normal windows software on Windows RT 8.1?

Tags: windows-rt, microsoft-surface-pro

In windows 8.1 pro I can run the normal PC software which usually runs on windows xp and windows 7 too.But can I run this softwares on Windows RT 8.1?It the os used on MS surface tab.Or I can only use apps which are available on windows store?

Comment: Windows RT is unable to run x86-64 software.  You can use any software located on the Windows Store.

Comment: The Surface and Surface 2 use Windows RT. The Surface Pro and Surface Pro 2 run Windows 8.1 Pro. You can only run apps from the Windows Store on Windows RT with the exception of the Office suite that is included.

Answer (score 0):

The RT version of Windows 8 restricts the ability to add software except for software currently available on the Windows Store.